# Retrieving data from previous ios app version

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

My company has an iOS app in the App Store. We are doing a complete teardown and starting from scratch but pushing it as an update since the old app will not even build. It is old with a lot of dependencies.

In the old app, users have favorited items which are stored in a sqlite database. The new app is storing them in a plist or using sqlite if it means we will not lose data. Is there any way to migrate that data to the new application?

This link makes me think it is possible, but I am not using Titanium: [Titanium - Retrieving SQLite Data from previous version of iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495832/titanium-retrieving-sqlite-data-from-previous-version-of-ios-app)

I am currently checking to see if the database exists when I launch the app and it is always logging "NO". Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
NSString *databaseName = @"my_client_database.sqlite";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]){
  NSLog(@"NO");
}else{
  NSLog(@"YES");
}
```

Comment: I guess you did already triple check that the database path is created in the exact same way (case matters, My_Client_Database.sqlite and my_client_database.sqlite are two different files on the iOS device) it was in the old app?

Comment: it means that file does not exist, you don't have database on disk.

Comment: I did triple check. The path is the exact same. Theoretically, it should exist. The records are being written to the database in the previous version so I know it is there.

Answer (score 1):

OK for anyone who needs to query data from a previous application:

1. Click Window > Devices
2. Select your device
3. Select your app
4. Click the gear
5. Click Show Container

This allows you to see exactly where the files are located if you know nothing about the previous version.

6. Download the container
7. Via terminal you can then inspect the sqlite database

Now that you know what you are working with you can look in the appropriate directory. Mine was in application support it turns out.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray *pathsList = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *directoryURL = [pathsList objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [[directoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_client_database.sqlite"] absoluteString];
```

At this point you can query the sqlite database and create new records appropriately!